# React Native: Save state of a custom splash screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, splash-screen, react-state

I'm new to React Native and trying to build a custom splash screen for my iOS app.In my app.js, I have `AppNavigator`. For now, I build `AppNavigator` and `SplashScreen` together, put my `SplashScreen` on top of the `AppNavigator` like this:

```
   <ToggleStorybook>
      <RootStoreProvider value={rootStore}>
        <SafeAreaProvider initialMetrics={initialWindowMetrics}>
          <ErrorBoundary catchErrors={"always"}>
            <Host>
              // Rendering the screen ...
              {showSplash && <SplashScreen />}
              <AppNavigator
                initialState={initialNavigationState}
                onStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
                onReady={() => {
                  routingInstrumentation.registerNavigationContainer(navigationRef)
                }}
              />
            </Host>
          </ErrorBoundary>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </RootStoreProvider>
    </ToggleStorybook>
```

But a problem comes.
I have a tutorial screen with a timer right under my `SplashScreen`. When I run the app, a splash screen is shown, and after 3 seconds, it goes to `TutorialScreen` but the screen seems like it's already run in 3 seconds, not running from the first tutorial.

The next problem comes.
I have `DashboardScreen` after the `TutorialScreen` that asks for location permission. The permission prompt is shown right on top of the `SplashScreen` while what I want is it to be shown after `SplashScreen` (right on the `DashboardScreen`).

I'm thinking of setting a timeout on every screen but it will make more problem occurs and of course, it will mess up my code. So I want to save the state of `SplashScreen` every time user runs the app and set it to false by default and if the user quits the app. How do I do it? If I use `Storage`, it will only save once the app launch not every time user re-runs the app.

I appreciate any help and questions, please ask if I have to explain it clearer. Thank you :)

Disclaimer: I can't use `react-native-splash-screen` library due to I need to get user data and show it in my splash screen

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because its **executing both components simultaneously**.

try below way with conditional rendering for splash and main app.
**This will execute one component at a time only.**

eg.

```
{
    showSplash
    ?
        <SplashScreen />
    :
        <AppNavigator
            initialState={initialNavigationState}
            onStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
            onReady={() => {
            routingInstrumentation.registerNavigationContainer(navigationRef)
            }}
        />
}
```

Comment: hi, already doing that but if i doing so there will be a blank space before the dashboard shown (after the splash screen rendered)

Comment: take the splash screen into the navigator itself and then replace the stack with new screen while navigation from splash to main screen